# Plot ROC from confidence ratings

Tags: r, probability, lme4, roc, proc-r-package

In my experiment participants rate their confidence concerning the distance between two stimuli previously presented on a 5 step scale (1 = sure they are near, 3 = don't know, 5 = sure they are far). The stimuli belong to 4 conditions (2x2 repeated measure design; see cond_A, cond_B in table).
Here is a summary of the long format dataframe that shows the two repeated conditions, the ID, the proportions (n trial/total for each ID) for that relevant confidence rating.

```
  cond_A   cond_B                 ID         1         2         3         4              5  tot
1   congr    far 5b6dada03ce3ab0001fd077c 0.0000000 0.2857143 0.1428571 0.4285714 0.1428571   7
2   congr    far 5c5d73cf0edbd90001e1ee27 0.0000000 0.1666667 0.1666667 0.6666667 0.0000000   6
3   congr    far 5c5e04ca6539fe00016e1afa 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.5714286 0.4285714 0.0000000   7
4   congr    far 5c66f284146af300015604c2 0.1428571 0.1428571 0.0000000 0.4285714 0.2857143   7
5   congr    far 5c7d57bb3454d70016499f1d 0.0000000 0.2000000 0.4000000 0.4000000 0.0000000   5
6   congr    far 5da0a0ce117b92001465fa35 0.0000000 0.2000000 0.2000000 0.0000000 0.6000000   5
```

tail of the df

```
  cond_A   cond_B                 ID                 1         2         3         4         5 tot
254 noncongr   near 60e5cd4e3d91b6025c62b9fe 0.2000000 0.3000000 0.1000000 0.4000000 0.0000000  10
255 noncongr   near 60e813572b209b50665a209c 0.5714286 0.1428571 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.2857143   7
256 noncongr   near 60e9503c04c84d717015c4b0 0.4000000 0.2000000 0.2000000 0.2000000 0.0000000   5
257 noncongr   near 60eafb146471ede7fb3773df 0.7500000 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.2500000   4
258 noncongr   near 60eb0d6a4080e2a6cbc9c7d3 0.2222222 0.4444444 0.1111111 0.2222222 0.0000000   9
259 noncongr   near 60ef4642202c8520a37e19b5 0.0000000 0.2857143 0.2857143 0.4285714 0.0000000   7
```

Please find here a plot that summarises the data

[image]

From that, I need to extract ROC curves (something like Chapter 3: Empirical ROCs https://rstudio-pubs-static.s3.amazonaws.com/371840_5694e490af85424eb7e7f3ae721cd67d.html#chapter-3-empirical-rocs) but cannot make heads or tails on how to do that.

Do you have any hints on how to run ROC analyses on this data? Or any other analyses that you think might be appropriate for this type of response?
Thanks for your help

Comment: What specifically would you like the output to be? An ROC plot using the aggregated data in each condition of your 2x2 design?

Comment: You tagged the question with the proc-r-package and lme4 tags. Is there something specific that you want to use from these packages?

Comment: @RoryS that is correct.

Comment: @Calimo I guess that pROC package could be used for this task but since I do not know how to proceed I do not know which functions could be useful..lme4 not really buy maybe glmer binomial

Comment: @atnplab I think the fact that you have a "don't know" midpoint on your scale might be problematic for what you're trying to do. An ROC plot is a plot of the hit rate against the false alarm rate at each level of your confidence rating scale, and I'm not sure it's possible to meaningfully classify "don't know" responses as either hits or misses. I'd seek further help/reading on this issue before going any further, or consider alternative analyses.